# Anyway to stop this mousewheel function temporary when pop up appears?

Tags: javascript, scroll, popup, mousewheel

```
// Depency on Jquery + http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js [Must Include]

if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

function wheel(event) {
    var delta = 0;
    if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
    else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;

    handle(delta);
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = false;
}

function handle(delta) {
    var time = 1000; // delay time
    var distance = 300; // delta point 
    // Dom where it will apply 
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - (distance * delta)
    }, time );
}// JavaScript Document
```

Anyway to stop this temporary while my menu pop up is open? actually just want to know if there are any code can disable this temporary and activate again after menu closes. My menu is working already just need a code to disable and enable this function.

Okay maybe more like anyways to uncall a function(I believe is wheel in this case) when the menu open and call it again ltr when menu closes.

Comment: you can check a bail-early flag at the top of wheel(), and toggle the flag from your menu show/hide routines.

Comment: @dandavis Hi, not very sure what you talking about, do you have any example to show how I should go about doing it?

Comment: `function wheel(event) { if(dialog.isShown) return; ... ` where _dialog.isShown+ is a property path controlled by the dialog handlers.

Comment: @dandavis From this code can you tell which is the function enabling the scrolling to occur? Now the problem for me is, I could not identify the main function that I can play with on enabling and disabling the scroll.

Comment: @Alvaro do you know anyway to work for this case?